# Docker stopped working with error message OCI runtime create failed

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, archlinux, manjaro, apparmor

I'm using Manjaro Linux and Kernerl 5.10.13.

I'm not sure what happened, maybe something was updated, but Docker stopped working for me.

When I try to do `docker run hello-world`, I see the following message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367:
starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: apply apparmor
profile: apparmor failed to apply profile: write /proc/self/attr/exec: invalid argument: unknown.

ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

If I switch to kernel 5.9.16, it seems to be fine. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Weird, it's working for me on Arch with linux 5.10.13.arch1-1 and docker 1:20.10.3-1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to enable apparmor in your kernel parameters (`apparmor=1 lsm=lockdown,yama,apparmor,bpf`)

See https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/ldhx0v/cant_start_docker_containers_on_latest_kernel/

Comment: Thank you @laktak, I was going to mark my response as the answer, but I think what you provided is more legit, and although my issue is gone now, I'm gonna mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened there, but the next morning (around 7 hours after I posted this), there was an update on my system, which seems to have resolved the issue